# Store data into different tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have a 2 tables

one is **plates**

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "container_slot_id": 3,
        "created_at": "2015-10-26 08:26:32",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-26 08:26:32"
    }
}
```

and the other is **plate_containers**

```
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mrs. Maritza Pollich DVM",
    "equipment_status_codes_id": 8,
}
```

And here is my controller

```
 public function storePlateCleaningData(PlateCleaningRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $plate = Plate::find($id);

       $data = $request->all();

        if ($plate->update($data)) {
            return response()->json([
                'Success' => [
                    'message' => 'Plate is Cleaned!'
                ]
            ], 201);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'Error' => [
                    'message' => 'Plate is not updated, something went wrong!'
                ]
            ], 400);
        }


    }
```

I want, when the user updates a `plate`, he must be able to update the `equipment_status_codes_id` of the **plate_containers** table. How can I achieve this? I can inject both models into my constructor, but now what?

**UPDATE**: Relations in tables

**plates** table

```
$table->integer('plate_container_id')->nullable()->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('plate_container_id')->references('id')->on('plate_containers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

And the models looks like this.

**Plate**

```
  public function plateContainer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PlateContainer');
    }
```

And **PlateContainer**

```
public function plates()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Plate');
}
```

Comment: How are the two tables related?

Comment: @Mysteryos I have updated the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**What i gather from your question is:**

A plate belongs to one Plate container.

If that is the case, try the code below for your controller (replace xxx with your `equipment_status_codes_id` :

```
public function storePlateCleaningData(PlateCleaningRequest $request, $id)
{
    //Let's eager load Plate Container
    $plate = Plate::with('plateContainer')->find($id);

   $data = $request->all();

    if ($plate->update($data)) {

        //Check if plate has container
        if($plate->plateContainer) {
            //Update plate container's equipment_status_codes_id 
            $plate->plateContainer->equipment_status_codes_id = xxx
            $plate->plateContainer->save();
        }

        return response()->json([
            'Success' => [
                'message' => 'Plate is Cleaned!'
            ]
        ], 201);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json([
            'Error' => [
                'message' => 'Plate is not updated, something went wrong!'
            ]
        ], 400);
    }


}
```